# Ask a Q based on a generated number in python 3.5

Tags: python, python-3.5

I am making a conversation simulator and am trying to make randomly generated questions, this is the code I have.

```
import time
print ("Hello")
time.sleep(2)
age = input("How old are you?")
time.sleep(2)
if age.isdigit() and age >= str(0):
    print ("Ok, cool I am " + age + " too.")
    time.sleep(2)
    yourname = input("What is your name again?")
    print ("Cool, " + yourname + " is a nice name")
    time.sleep(2)
    name = input("Do you remember my name?")
    print ("Ya my name is " + name + " you got it")
    from random import randint
    print(randint(0,4))
    elif randint = 1
        print ("hello")
    elif randint = 2
        print ("hello")
    elif randint = 3
        print ("hello")
    elif randint = 4
        print ("hello")
    elif randint = 5
else:
    print ("ERROR")
```

I am trying to ask a random question from a random integer value.
I honestly cannot find out what is wrong and I am still learning python 3.5.

Comment: The comparison operator is `==` not `=`.

Comment: And `randint` is the function not the random value. You have to assign the return value of the `randint()` call to a variable.

Comment: I don't get what you mean by You have to assign the return value of the randint() call to a variable.

Comment: You should probably tell us what behavior you observe and what you did expect. I assume that your posted source code gives syntax error, otherwise you have to make sure you post the code you actually try to run.